# How to initialize an array of structs inside a function?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I declare an array of struct in main and send as an argument to function called "change". In function "change", I try to initialize the array but get en error.

```
/* main.c file */
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Word arr[MAX_ARRAY];
    change(&arr);
    return 0;
}



/* header.h file*/
#ifndef UNTITLED_HEADER_H
#define UNTITLED_HEADER_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY 1000

typedef struct Word *Word;
enum WordTag {FIRST_WORD, INFO_WORD1, INFO_WORD2};

void change(Word *arr);

#endif



/* functions.c */
#include "header.h"
#include "data.h"

void change(Word *arr) {

    struct Word *word;
    word->tag = INFO_WORD2;
    word->type.info2.are = 4;
    word->type.info2.dest = 1;
    word->type.info2.source = 1;
    arr[5] = word;
}



/* data.h */
#ifndef UNTITLED_DATA_H
#define UNTITLED_DATA_H

#include "header.h"

struct FirstWord {
    unsigned int are : 3;
    unsigned int destOperand : 4;
    unsigned int sourceOperand : 4;
    unsigned int opcode : 4;
};

struct InfoWord1 {
    unsigned int are : 3;
    unsigned int op : 12;
};

struct InfoWord2 {
    unsigned int are : 3;
    unsigned int dest : 3;
    unsigned int source : 3;
};

struct Word {
    enum WordTag tag;
    union {
        struct FirstWord first;
        struct InfoWord1 info1;
        struct InfoWord2 info2;
    } type;
};

#endif
```

When I try to run it, I get an error in the line:

```
word->tag = INFO_WORD2;
```

which appears in file functions.c.

I will mention that I need to compile it without getting any warnings with the flags:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c functions.c
```

In addition, I will mention, this is only an example to my real code. Therefor, here I change only arr[5] (as an example), but I wouldn't really know which index I will need to initialize in advance inside function "change". Therefor, I send the complete array and can't send as an argument to "change" the specific pointer to the struct I need to initialize.

Comment: In the change function you define a pointer to a struct Word but you don’t initialize the pointer. It points to nothing so doing anything with it results in undefined behavior.

Comment: `change(&arr)` is also wrong.  Did you mean `change(arr)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gerwin pointed out, you're using an uninitialized pointer in `change()`.

This is one change you can make to address the problem (there are always many ways to skin a cat :) ):

```
void change(Word *arr) {

    struct Word *word = (struct Word*)malloc( sizeof( struct Word ) );
    word->tag = INFO_WORD2;
    word->type.info2.are = 4;
    word->type.info2.dest = 1;
    word->type.info2.source = 1;
    arr[0] = *word;
    free( word );
}
```

You really don't even need a heap variable for this, though. Even simpler:

```
void change(Word *arr) {

    struct Word word;
    word.tag = INFO_WORD2;
    word.type.info2.are = 4;
    word.type.info2.dest = 1;
    word.type.info2.source = 1;
    arr[0] = word;
}
```

And this is a more direct way of doing what you're currently doing:

```
void change(Word *arr) {
    arr->tag = INFO_WORD2;
    arr->type.info2.are = 4;
    arr->type.info2.dest = 1;
    arr->type.info2.source = 1;
}
```

Comment: After I saw the answer I understood that my question wasn't clear enough, so I updated the question. Anyway, the first option did solve my problem and I also changed as @jamesdlin suggested from `change(&arr)` to `change(arr)`. Thank you all for the help!